# How to Get an Aggregate from a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

The following collection contains the ticks for the diverse exchange symbols (in this case `BTCUSD` and `BTCEUR`):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a08d2b956df9b2302759d1a"), "symbol" : "BTCUSD", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-13T00:00:00Z"), "open" : 112, "close" : 91.1, "high" : 130, "low" : 81.12, "volume" : 23866.6770456 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a08d2b956df9b2302759d1c"), "symbol" : "BTCUSD", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-14T00:00:00Z"), "open" : 91.1, "close" : 90.171, "high" : 109, "low" : 20, "volume" : 16437.2196645 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a08d2b956df9b2302759d1e"), "symbol" : "BTCEUR", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-15T00:00:00Z"), "open" : 89.86, "close" : 83.302, "high" : 104, "low" : 71.497, "volume" : 16393.12856398 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a08d2b956df9b2302759d20"), "symbol" : "BTCEUR", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-16T00:00:00Z"), "open" : 84.27, "close" : 67.588, "high" : 84.48, "low" : 0.01, "volume" : 26092.5432296 }
```

How do I get the list of symbols actually present in the collection in `Go`? For instance, the result I'm looking for is:

```
{ "BTCUSD", "BTCEUR" }
```

This would let me retrieve the latest tick values from the exchange service without having to store somewhere the symbols I'm interested in.

From the `mongo` shell I've tried this...

```
db.candles.aggregate({$group: {_id:"$symbol"}})
```

... and here is the result:

```
{ "_id" : "BTCUSD" }
{ "_id" : "BTCEUR" }
```

What is the equivalent in `Go` using `mgo`? Is it possible to just get an array of symbols instead of a collection of `"_id" : "value"` pairs?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems do you have? Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: See updates in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `Distinct()`

What you want is easiest done using [`collection.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). In MongoDB console it would look like this:

```
db.candles.distinct("symbol")
```

And in Go, using `mgo`,  [`Query.Distinct()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Distinct):

```
var sess *mgo.Session = ... // Acquire session
c := sess.DB("dbname").C("candles")

var symbols []string
err := c.Find(nil).Distinct("symbol", &symbols)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(symbols)
```

### Using the Aggregation Framework

You can also do it using MongoDB aggregation, which is available via the [`Collection.Pipe()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Pipe) method. You have to pass a slice to it, each element corresponds to an aggregation stage.

The result of an aggregation is always a list of documents, so if you want the result as a slice of strings, you have to do the "conversion" manually.

```
var sess *mgo.Session = ... // Acquire session
c := sess.DB("dbname").C("candles")

pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id": "$symbol",
        },
    },
})
var results = []bson.M{}
if err := pipe.All(&results); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    return
}

// results holds {"_id": "symbol"} documents
// To get a slice of symbols:
symbols := make([]string, len(results))
for i, doc := range results {
    symbols[i] = doc["_id"].(string)
}
fmt.Println(symbols)
```

For more techniques how to get a slice of values result instead of documents, see [Is there a way to get slice as result of Find()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317887/is-there-a-way-to-get-slice-as-result-of-find/49319677#49319677)

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Regarding performance, is there anything to take into account considering that the collection contains thousands and thousands of documents?

Comment: @j3d Yes, the distinct operation is always "slow". If you need to do this many times and it needs to be fast, you may consider keeping this info saved, e.g. when you insert a new document, also upsert the symbol into a different collection, keeping the distinct symbols.