# Get a value in a reference of a lookup with MongoDB and Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have the structures below. I use **Golang 1.9.2**.

```
// EventBoost describes the model of a EventBoost
type EventBoost struct {
  ID          string    `bson:"_id" json:"_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  CampaignID  string    `bson:"_campaign_id" json:"_campaign_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  Name        string    `bson:"name" json:"name"`
  Description string    `bson:"description" json:"description"`
  Level       string    `bson:"level" json:"level"`
  EventID     string    `bson:"_event_id" json:"_event_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  StartDate   time.Time `bson:"start_date" json:"start_date"`
  EndDate     time.Time `bson:"end_date" json:"end_date"`
  IsPublished bool      `bson:"is_published" json:"is_published"`
  CreatedBy   string    `bson:"created_by" json:"created_by"`
  CreatedAt   time.Time `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
  ModifiedAt  time.Time `bson:"modified_at" json:"modified_at"`
}

// LocationBoost describes the model of a LocationBoost
type LocationBoost struct {
  ID          string    `bson:"_id" json:"_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  CampaignID  string    `bson:"_campaign_id" json:"_campaign_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  Name        string    `bson:"name" json:"name"`
  Description string    `bson:"description" json:"description"`
  Level       string    `bson:"level" json:"level"`
  LocationID  string    `bson:"_location_id" json:"_location_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
  StartDate   time.Time `bson:"start_date" json:"start_date"`
  EndDate     time.Time `bson:"end_date" json:"end_date"`
  IsPublished bool      `bson:"is_published" json:"is_published"`
  CreatedBy   string    `bson:"created_by" json:"created_by"`
  CreatedAt   time.Time `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
  ModifiedAt  time.Time `bson:"modified_at" json:"modified_at"`
}

// Campaign describes the model of a Campaign
type Campaign struct {
    ID               string           `bson:"_id" json:"_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
    Name             string           `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Description      string           `bson:"description" json:"description"`
    EventBoostIDs    []string         `bson:"event_boost_ids" json:"event_boost_ids"`
    LocationBoostIDs []string         `bson:"location_boost_ids" json:"location_boost_ids"`
    StartDate        time.Time        `bson:"start_date" json:"start_date"`
    EndDate          time.Time        `bson:"end_date" json:"end_date"`
    IsPublished      bool             `bson:"is_published" json:"is_published"`
    CreatedBy        string           `bson:"created_by" json:"created_by"`
    CreatedAt        time.Time        `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    ModifiedAt       time.Time        `bson:"modified_at" json:"modified_at"`
}
```

A **Campaign** (understand a marketing campaign) is made of **Events** or **Locations** that can be boosted with a level (basic or premium). A campaign has a start and a end date, so do have the boosts.

The function `GetEventLevel` has to return me the level of a given event.

```
// GetEventLevel of an event
func (dao *campaignDAO) GetEventLevel(eventID string) (string, error) {
}
```

If the event is boosted in *an active campaign* (`isPublished` is `true`), and *the boost is active* (`isPublished` is `true`) and *the now date is between the start and end date of the boost*, then my Event is **boosted**, so the function returns the level (basic or premium). Else, it returns `"standard"`.

My question is : **can I do this fully with Mongo ? Or do I need to perform some logic in the DAO with Golang ?**

If I can do this with Mongo, what I hope, I have no idea how to do this. From what I understand, I would first need to lookup the events and the locations of the campaign, and then search in it with dates, but..

Comment: If your `Campaign` does not contain `EventBoost`s and `LocationBoost`s embedded (just their IDs), then their type should be a slice of `string` (type of `Campaign.EventBoostIDs` and `Campaign.LocationBoostIDs` should be `[]string`). Is this correct that you store them in different collections? Or you populate these in your DAO?

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong copy/paste.. These are strings of course. Let me edit the original post.

Comment: Also what's the use of storing these in `Campaign`? Because if the boosts also store the `Campaign` ID, they can be queried by filtering for Campaign ID?

Comment: The CampaignID could be removed from the `EventBoost` and `LocationBoost`, or the IDs in the Campaign, that is correct, but I want to keep it as of now.

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? A MongoDB (console) query or how to do it in Go (using `mgo`)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, I would like to know how to do it in Golang with `mgo` yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing *most* (and the hardest part) of what you want can easily be done in MongoDB. The final step when returning "basic", "premium" or "standard" most likely can also be done, but I think it's not worth the hassle as that is trivial in Go.

In MongoDB use the [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for this. This is available in the `mgo` package via the [`Collection.Pipe()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Pipe) method. You have to pass a slice to it, each element corresponds to an aggregation stage. Read this answer for more details: [How to Get an Aggregate from a MongoDB Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379455/how-to-get-an-aggregate-from-a-mongodb-collection/47388623#47388623)

Back to your example. Your `GetEventLevel()` method could be implemented like this:

```
func (dao *campaignDAO) GetEventLevel(eventID string) (string, error) {
    c := sess.DB("").C("eventboosts") // sess represents a MongoDB Session
    now := time.Now()
    pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {
            "$match": bson.M{
                "_event_id":    eventID,            // Boost for the specific event
                "is_published": true,               // Boost is active
                "start_date":   bson.M{"$lt": now}, // now is between start and end
                "end_date":     bson.M{"$gt": now}, // now is between start and end
            },
        },
        {
            "$lookup": bson.M{
                "from":         "campaigns",
                "localField":   "_campaign_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as":           "campaign",
            },
        },
        {"$unwind": "$campaign"},
        {
            "$match": bson.M{
                "campaign.is_published": true,      // Attached campaign is active
            },
        },
    })

    var result []*EventBoost
    if err := pipe.All(&result); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if len(result) == 0 {
        return "standard", nil
    }
    return result[0].Level, nil
}
```

If you only need at most one `EventBoost` (or there may not be more at the same time), use `$limit` stage to limit results to a single one, and use `$project` to only fetch the `level` field and nothing more.

Use this pipeline for the above mentioned simplification / optimization:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$match": bson.M{
            "_event_id":    eventID,            // Boost for the specific event
            "is_published": true,               // Boost is active
            "start_date":   bson.M{"$lt": now}, // now is between start and end
            "end_date":     bson.M{"$gt": now}, // now is between start and end
        },
    },
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "campaigns",
            "localField":   "_campaign_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "campaign",
        },
    },
    {"$unwind": "$campaign"},
    {
        "$match": bson.M{
            "campaign.is_published": true,      // Attached campaign is active
        },
    },
    {"$limit": 1},             // Fetch at most 1 result
    {
        "$project": bson.M{
            "_id":   0,        // We don't even need the EventBoost's ID
            "level": "$level", // We do need the level and nothing more
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: I really thank you, that is a huge help ! I also learned a new concept : `$unwind`. And it is working so.. Thanks.

Comment: If I could add a remark, you use `result[0].Level` in case there are multiple results, which is quite smart. But if I am sure that an Event cannot be boosted many times at the same time (prevent from doing it when saving), we could use `One()` instead ?

Comment: @Elwyn I advise not to use `Pipe.One()` in this case, as `One()` expects a result. If there is no result, it returns an error (although you could just as easily compare to `mgo.ErrNotFound`). So I opted to use `All()` which does not return an error if there are no results. You may also add a `$limit` stage to only fetch a single result, and also use `$project` to only return the `level` and omit the rest of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I will take a look at `$project` that I do not know yet.

Comment: @Elwyn Added the optimization to fetch at most 1 result, and exclude everything else except the level. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only storing IDs to reference documents in other collections, rather than de-normalizing the data entirely, no, you cannot do this purely in MongoDB. MongoDB is not a relational database. What you're describing is exactly what MongoDB was designed *not* to do.

You'll need to perform the logic in Go; whether you do so in the DAO is up to you, but personally, I would lean toward a simple method on the type that does the logic on the fly based on the field values, e.g. `Campaign.GetEventLevel` or something along those lines. Having a method that fine-grained in your DAO implies to me some unusual design decisions that don't suit the MongoDB model very well. For the most part, with MongoDB, you want to retrieve you documents (objects) and work with them in your app. Trying to perform query logic in MongoDB as you would with a typical RDBMS is going to lead to frustration and poor performance.

Comment: Hello, as the answer shows it above, it is not correct. Anyway, regarding the relation you mention, it is allowed to perform some lookups in Mongo. I use something called a DTO in my software, so that the objects that go from the DAO to the API are looked-up in full objects. But for many reason, I prefer to store them as relations (in this case, I also use embeded objects)