# Is there a way to get slice as result of Find()?

Tags: mongodb, go, slice, mgo

Now I'm doing:

```
sess := mongodb.DB("mybase").C("mycollection")
var users []struct {
    Username string `bson:"username"`
}

err = sess.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "_id": 0}).All(&users)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

var myUsers []string
for _, user := range users{
    myUsers = append(myUsers, user.Username)
}
```

Is there a more effective way to get slice with usernames from Find (or another search function) directly, without struct and range loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a MongoDB `find()` is always a list of documents. So if you want a list of values, you have to convert it manually just as you did.

### Using a custom type (derived from `string`)

Also note that if you would create your own type (derived from `string`), you could override its unmarshaling logic, and "extract" just the `username` from the document.

This is how it could look like:

```
type Username string

func (u *Username) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    doc := bson.M{}
    if err = raw.Unmarshal(&doc); err != nil {
        return
    }
    *u = Username(doc["username"].(string))
    return
}
```

And then querying the usernames into a slice:

```
c := mongodb.DB("mybase").C("mycollection") // Obtain collection

var uns []Username
err = c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "_id": 0}).All(&uns)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(uns)
```

Note that `[]Username` is not the same as `[]string`, so this may or may not be sufficient to you. Should you need a user name as a value of `string` instead of `Username` when processing the result, you can simply convert a `Username` to `string`.

### Using `Query.Iter()`

Another way to avoid the slice copying would be to call [`Query.Iter()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Iter), iterate over the results and extract and store the `username` manually, similarly how the above custom unmarshaling logic does.

This is how it could look like:

```
var uns []string
it := c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "_id": 0}).Iter()
defer it.Close()
for doc := (bson.M{}); it.Next(&doc); {
    uns = append(uns, doc["username"].(string))
}
if err := it.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(uns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what could be more effective than a simple `range` loop with `append`s. Without all the Mongo stuff your code basically is this and that's exactly how I would do this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Username string
}

func main() {

    var users []User
    users = append(users, User{"John"}, User{"Jane"}, User{"Jim"}, User{"Jean"})
    fmt.Println(users)

    // Interesting part starts here.
    var myUsers []string
    for _, user := range users {
        myUsers = append(myUsers, user.Username)
    }
    // Interesting part ends here.

    fmt.Println(myUsers)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/qCwENmemn-R

Comment: I mean, is there a way to get slice from Find (or another search function) directly, without struct and range loop?